# Abstracting NLog via an interface but retaining the logging class

Tags: nlog

I have abstracted out by logging into an interface and then injecting the customer class.

When the custom class is logging the logger name if the name of the custom class, e.g.

CommonLibrary.Logging.NLog

I need it to say the name of the previous method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you provide the wrapped-logger-type to the NLog-Logger-Log-method, then it will be ignored in the callsite-logic.

See also:

https://github.com/NLog/NLog/blob/4c0acefa3d394f768b46ac8ba0cb39a018565ce4/examples/ExtendingLoggers/LoggerWrapper/Program.cs#L72

Answer (score 0):

I have not used these but version 4.3.9 introduced cleanNamesOfAnonymousDelegates and version 4.5 introduced cleanNamesOfAsyncContinuations

[NLog Callsite layout](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Callsite-layout-renderer)

In the past I have used a function to change the logger name before it writes the log message to filter out/ignore the facade logging functions from the stacktrace.

```
internal string GetCallingMethodName()
{
    string result = "unknown";
    StackTrace trace = new StackTrace(false);
    for (int i = 0; i < trace.FrameCount; i++)
    {
        StackFrame frame = trace.GetFrame(i);
        MethodBase method = frame.GetMethod();
        Type dt = method.DeclaringType;
        if (!typeof(Logger).IsAssignableFrom(dt) && method.DeclaringType.Namespace != "<NAMESPACE TO SKIP>")
        {
            result = string.Concat(method.DeclaringType.FullName, ".", method.Name);
            break;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you like to "hide" your assembly in the stacktrace, if so, then you could use:

```
LogManager.AddHiddenAssembly(myAssembly)
```

See http://nlog-project.org/documentation/v4.4.0/html/M_NLog_LogManager_AddHiddenAssembly.htm